# Extend SkShapeNode to get rectangle position in n x m matrix

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, extension-methods, skshapenode

I'm using `SKShapeNode` to add rectangles in a n x m matrix. Now I want to store the n x m
 position in the `SKShapeNode`. Of course I could simply use the .name property and store the n x m position as string. This has the disadvantage that when I'm trying to access the position I always have to struggle with a string instead of a point.

Is there an easy way to extend the SKShapeNode type in order to get something like this:

```
sampleSkShapeNode.rectanglePosition -> Point(v,h)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`userData`](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKNode/userData) property of `SKShapeNode` which can be set to an
arbitrary `NSMutableDictionary`, for example

```
sampleSkShapeNode.userData = ["vpos": v, "hpos": h]
```